# Alphanumerical sorting not working in Array

Tags: powershell

We have a directory, which features many subdirectories (one per day) with serveral files in it. Unfortunately, files can be resent - so a file of 2020-01-01 can be resend (with slightly different filename, since a timestamp is added to the filename) on 2020-02-03. The structure looks something like this:

- TopDir

  - 20200801

    - AFile_20200801_20200801150000 (Timestamped 2020-08-01 15:00:00)
    - BFile_20200801_20200801150000
    - CFile_20200801_20200801150000
  - 20200802

    - AFile_20200802_20200801150000
    - BFile_20200802_20200801150000
    - CFile_20200802_20200801150000
    - AFile_20200801_20200802150000 (Timestamped 2020-08-02 15:00:00)

So the AFile of 2020-08-01 has been resent on 2020-08-02 at 3 PM.

I am now trying to retrieve a list with the most recent file per day, so I built up an array and populated it with all files below TopDir (recurively). So far so good, all files are found:

```
$path = "Y:\";

$FileArray = @()
$FileNameArray = @()

$FileArrayCounter = 0

foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse)
    {
      if ($item.Extension -ne "")
      {
        $StringPart1, $StringPart2, $StringPart3, $StringPart4 = $item.Name.Split('_');
        $FileNameShort = "{0}_{1}_{2}" -f $StringPart1.Trim(), $StringPart2.Trim(), $StringPart3.Trim();
        $FileNameShort = $FileNameShort.Trim().ToUpper();

        $FileArray += @{FileID = $FileArrayCounter; FileNameShort = $FileNameShort; FileName = $item.Name; FullName = $item.FullName; LastWriteTime = $item.LastWriteTime};
        $FileArrayCounter ++;
      }
    }


$FileArray = $FileArray | sort FileNameShort; #@{Expression={"FileNameShort"}; Ascending=$True} #, @{Expression={"LastWriteTime"}; Descending=$True}

foreach($f in $FileArray)
{
    Write-host($f.FileNameShort, $f.LastWriteTime)
}

Write-host($FileArrayCounter.ToString() + " Dateien gefunden");
```

The newly added column "FileNameShort" includes a substring of the filename. With this done, I receive two Rows for `AFile_20200801`:

- AFile_20200801, AFile_20200801_20200801150000, ...
- AFile_20200801, AFile_20200801_20200802150000, ...

However, when I try to sort my array (see above code), the output is NOT sorted by name. Instead I receive something like the following:

- AFile_20200801
- CFile_20200802
- AFile_20200801
- BFile_20200801

What I want to achieve is a sorting by FileNameShort ASCENDING and LastWriteTime DESCENDING.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sort does not work because `$FileArray` is an array of hash tables. The syntax `Sort FileNameShort` is binding the `FileNameShort` property to the `-Property` parameter of `Sort-Object`. However, the hash table does not contain a property called `FileShortName`. You can see this if you run `$FileArray[0] | Get-Member`.

If you create them as custom objects, the simple sort syntax works.

```
$FileArray += [pscustomobject]@{FileID = $FileArrayCounter; FileNameShort = $FileNameShort; FileName = $item.Name; FullName = $item.FullName; LastWriteTime = $item.LastWriteTime}
$FileArray | Sort FileNameShort # This will sort correctly
```

---

As an aside, I do not recommend using `+=` to seemingly add elements to an array. It is best to either output the results inside of your loop and save the loop results or create a list with an `.Add()` method. The problem with `+=` is the current array is expanded into memory and those contents are then used to create a new array with the new items. As the array grows, it becomes increasingly non-performant. See below for a more efficient example.

```
$FileArray = foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse)
    {
      if ($item.Extension -ne "")
      {
        $StringPart1, $StringPart2, $StringPart3, $StringPart4 = $item.Name.Split('_');
        $FileNameShort = "{0}_{1}_{2}" -f $StringPart1.Trim(), $StringPart2.Trim(), $StringPart3.Trim();
        $FileNameShort = $FileNameShort.Trim().ToUpper();
        # Outputting custom object here
        [pscustomobject]@{FileID = $FileArrayCounter; FileNameShort = $FileNameShort; FileName = $item.Name; FullName = $item.FullName; LastWriteTime = $item.LastWriteTime};
        $FileArrayCounter ++;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution:

`$FileArray = $FileArray | sort @{Expression={[string]$_.FileNameShort}; Ascending=$True}, @{Expression={[datetime]$_.LastWriteTime}; Descending=$True}`

Still I don't know, why the first sorting did not work as expected.